# how do I add or subtract elapsed time from a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and return result in the same format?

Tags: php, date, format, strtotime

How do I subtract and/or add elapsed time to a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?
ie how do I add 16:49:13 to 2012-06-18 22:03:18 ?

Also, how do I subtract 16:49:13 from 2012-06-19 14:52:31?
I need the results to be in the format hh:mm:ss

Comment: do you want to do this with php or with mysql?

Comment: How are you getting those time strings?

Comment: I am getting them from a very large excel document(contains about 50 000 dates at a time). I upload them into a PHP system i am developing.

I am writing code using the following formulae

DURATION = ENDDATE - STARTDATE
ENDDATE = STARTDATE + DURATION
STARTDATE = ENDDATE - DURATION.

I need to return the DURATION in the format HH:MM:SS.
But, i need to return the STARTDATE & ENDDATE in the format
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Comment: OK, see my answer, you can output the result in whatever format you wish using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my quick idea:

```
<?php

$a="16:49:13"; 
$e=explode(':', $a);

$y="2012-06-18 22:03:18";

echo  date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime("+ $e[0] hours $e[1] minutes $e[2] seconds ",strtotime($y)));
```

output: 19-06-2012 02:52:31

Comment: However, the second challenge is subtracting $a from $y

Comment: change the + to a - in the strtotime()

Comment: Ah! thanks for the tip. i think the last thing is implemeting a little regex validation for YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS before I do any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Given two times such as: `23:54:23` and `16:49:13`, you want the output to still be in HH:MM:SS format, representing the total amount of hours, minutes, and seconds resulting from the sum of the two dates (should output `40:43:36`):

You can use this function:

```
function addTime($t1, $t2)
{
    $t1a = explode(':', $t1);
    $t2a = explode(':', $t2);

    $h = $t1a[0] + $t2a[0] + ((($t1a[1] + $t2a[1]) / 60) >= 1 ? 1 : 0);
    $m = (($t1a[1] + $t2a[1]) % 60) + ((($t1a[2] + $t2a[2]) / 60) >= 1 ? 1 : 0);
    $s = ($t1a[2] + $t2a[2]) % 60;

    if($m == 60)
    {
        $h++;
        $m = 0;
    }

    $h = strlen($h) < 2 ? '0'.$h : $h;
    $m = strlen($m) < 2 ? '0'.$m : $m;
    $s = strlen($s) < 2 ? '0'.$s : $s;

    return "$h:$m:$s";
}
```

---

```
$t1 = '23:54:23'; 
$t2 = '16:49:13';

echo addTime($t1, $t2); // 40:43:36
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of PHP's [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/datetime) for this. Something along the lines of:-

To add:-

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("2012-06-18 22:03:18");
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", "16:49:13");
$seconds += $minutes * 60;
$seconds += $hours * 3600;
$interval = new DateInterval("PT{$seconds}S");
$dateTime->add($interval);
```

To subtract:-

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("2012-06-18 22:03:18");
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", "16:49:13");
$seconds += $minutes * 60;
$seconds += $hours * 3600;
$interval = new DateInterval("PT{$seconds}S");
$dateTime->sub($interval);
```

Then use the [`DateTime::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function to output the result any way you wish.

The datetime object wiill look after stuff such as leap years, time zones etc for you. These are all things that can easily make time calculations a pain in the ..

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using strtotime function:

```
$myTime      = strtotime('2012-06-18 22:03:18');
$delta       = (16 * 60 * 60) + (49 * 60) + 13;
$myTimeMinus = $myTime - $delta;
$myTimePlus  = $myTime + $delta;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $myTimeMinus);

//2012-06-18 05:14:05

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $myTimePlus);
// 2012-06-19 14:52:31
```